# children slideDown inside parent slideDown overflows the parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow, slidedown

A have designed a two level menu using jquery. When I hover the top menu link, a DIV by class name of **submenu** slides down. inside this div there is a link when I hover it, The second level with class name of **subsubmenu** is sliding down again and causes its parent (**submenu**) to expand more.

This structure works fine when you act slow and normal. The problem is that when I move my mouse quick around and exit and enter to top level menu many times, the structure becomes broken **for ever**! I mean the expansion of subsubmenu will no more expands its parent (submenu) even you act slow and normal again.

Is this a bug (In both google chrome and firefox!)? Or do you suggest any structural modification?

```js
$(".menuholder").on("mouseenter",function(){
var submenuid=$(this).attr("id").replace("menu","");
$(this).children("a").addClass("hover");
$(".submenu").stop().hide();
$("#submenu"+submenuid).stop().slideDown();
});

$(".menuholder").on("mouseleave",function(){
var submenuid=$(this).attr("id").replace("menu","");
$(this).children("a").removeClass("hover");
$(".submenu").stop().hide();
})

$(".subholder").on("mouseenter",function(){
$(".subsubmenu").stop().slideUp();
$(this).find(".subsubmenu").stop().slideDown();
});

$(".subholder").on("mouseleave",function(){
$(this).find(".subsubmenu").stop().slideUp();
})
```

```css
.menu{
 color:#ffffff;
 display:inline-block;
 padding-right:8px;
 padding-left:8px;
 background:#dfa800;
 white-space:nowrap;
 height:35px;
 line-height:35px;
 margin-left:5px;;
 border-top-right-radius:5px;
 border-top-left-radius:5px;
}
.menu:hover,.menu.hover{
 color:#000000;
    background:#eeeeee;
}
.submenu{
 width:200px;
 position:absolute;
 top:35px;
 background:#eeeeee;
 left:20px;
 z-index:900;
 display:none;
 box-shadow:0 10px 10px #000000;
}

.subholder{
 display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu7" class="menuholder" style="display: inline-block">
  <a class="menu">test</a>
  <div id="submenu7" class="submenu">
   <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
     <td valign="top" width="100%">
      <div class="subholder">
       <ul>
        <li>test</li>
       </ul>
       <div class="subsubmenu" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
         <li>test</li>
         <li>test</li>
         <li>test</li>
         <li>test</li>
         <li>test</li>
         <li>test</li>
         <li>test</li>
         <li>test</li>
         <li>test</li>
         <li>test</li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `.stop(true, true)` instead of `.stop()` to stop animation immediately and to clear animation's queue?

Comment: It seems working fine! in my case do you know why the structure is broken for ever?!

Comment: Nope, neither I inspected code narrowly nor I tested it a lot. Let's just say that if you do it in correct way, there is no need to search how something goes wrong.

Comment: Yes sure. I was going to suggest you to post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to many animations in short time, and only last one should be shown, you can use `.stop(true, true)` to not only stop animation, but also to complete it and to clear queue of animations.

It does help in some situations, when many animations (which are stopped on half-way) can cause weird behaviour.